# Page redirects to SITEURL in codeigniter. If it takes wrong path then it redirects to SITEURL, where as it should go to pagenot found?

Tags: routes, codeigniter-2

Page redirects to SITEURL in codeigniter. I have set paths in routes.php, If it takes wrong path then it redirects to SITEURL, where as it should go to pagenot found? What to do for this?

Now if I have have opened the link `http://mytest.com/city/[any dummy data]`, it should redirect to pagenotfound page. But it shoes the data from `http://mytest.com/`

in routes.php I have written below code.

```
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
$route['404_override'] = 'pagenotfound';`enter code here`
$route['profile/add_to_favorites'] = "profile/add_to_favorites"; 
$route['city/(:any)/welcome/venue_display/(:any)'] = "welcome/venue_display"; 
$route['city'] = "welcome";   `enter code here`
$route['city/(:any)'] = "welcome";
```

Answer (score 0):

you write:

Now if I have have opened the link http://mytest.com/city/[any dummy data]

but i your  routes you have:

$route['city/(:any)'] = "welcome";

so wouldn't that route [any dummy data] to your welcome controller?

in the application/errors directory, look for the file error_404.php  can you not just modify that file?